# Flask-Bcrypt Run time error

Tags: python, flask, bcrypt, password-encryption, flask-login

I was finishing up a simple little user login with *Flask* and *Bcrypt*.  However, when trying to login with a user that is stored in my database, I keep encountering a *runtime error*.  It looks like some sort of `loop` that's breaking.  Being that I'm pretty new to programming, this has been incredibly challenging to figure out what I'm doing wrong.  Hopefully someone here can help out! I'll past the relevant code below:

Here's the issue I'm getting.  It just keeps looping this until it exceeds the maximum:

> ```
>  File "C:\Users\desktop\test\app\models.py", line 37, in password
>    return self.password
>  File "C:\Users\.virtualenvs\flask\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\ext\hybrid.py",
> ```
>
> line 742, in **get**
>          return self.fget(instance)
>        File "C:\Users\desktop\test\app\models.py", line 37, in password

Models.py

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    nickname = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100))
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy='dynamic',
                            primaryjoin="User.id==Post.user_id")
    about_me = db.Column(db.String(140))
    last_seen = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    followed = db.relationship('User',
                                secondary=followers,
                                primaryjoin=(followers.c.follower_id == id),
                                secondaryjoin=(followers.c.followed_id == id),
                                backref=db.backref('followers', lazy='dynamic'),
                                lazy='dynamic')


    @hybrid_property
    def password(self):
        return self.password



    @password.setter
    def set_password(self, plaintext):
        self.password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(plaintext)

    def is_correct_password(self, plaintext):
        return bcrypt.check_password_hash(self.password, plaintext)
```

Forms.py

```
class LoginForm(Form):
    nickname = TextField('Nickname', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
```

Views.py Login

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(nickname=form.nickname.data).first_or_404()
        if user.is_correct_password(form.password.data):
            login_user(user)
            flash("you've been logged in!, 'success'")
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
        else:
            flash('your email or password doesnt match!', 'error')
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template('login.html',
                            title='Sign In',
                            form=form)
```

Views.py Registration

```
@app.route('/register', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def register():
    form = forms.RegisterForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User(nickname=form.nickname.data, emai=form.email.data, password=form.password.data)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('User successfully registered')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template('register.html', form=form)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use different names for column and property

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(100))

    @hybrid_property
    def password(self):
        return self.password_hash

    @password.setter
    def set_password(self, plaintext):
        self.password_hash = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(plaintext)
```

Comment: Changed def password to def password_hash and then changing the `@password.setter` property to `@password_hash.setter`. New error when trying to login.  if user.is_correct_password(form.password.data):
line 44, in is_correct_password
return bcrypt.check_password_hash(self.password, plaintext)
 line 193, in check_password_hash
return safe_str_cmp(bcrypt.hashpw(password, pw_hash), pw_hash)
\bcrypt\__init__.py", line 63, in hashpw
retval = _bcrypt.lib.crypt_rn(password, salt, hashed, len(hashed))
TypeError: initializer for ctype 'char *' must be a cdata pointer, not NoneType

Comment: But otherwise you fix did seem to work! So thank you.